# AngularJS: Make forward and back buttons call json data, but only if the item has a certain value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I already have forward and back buttons paging through data items in a array within a json file:

Controller:

```
dishControllers.controller('DrinkcardsController', ['$scope','$http','$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
$http.get('js/all.json').success(function(data) {
$scope.IsVisible = false;
        $scope.ShowHide = function () {
            $scope.IsVisible = $scope.IsVisible ? false : true;
        }

$scope.dish = data;
$scope.whichItem = $routeParams.itemId;

if ($routeParams.itemId > 0) {
  $scope.prevItem = Number($routeParams.itemId)-1;
} else {
  $scope.prevItem = $scope.dish.length-1;
}

if ($routeParams.itemId < $scope.dish.length-1) {
  $scope.nextItem = Number($routeParams.itemId)+1;
} else {
  $scope.nextItem = 0;
}
});
}]);
```

Html:

```
<a ng-href="#/sidecards/{{prevItem}}"><div class="lbut">&laquo;</div></a>
<a ng-href="#/sidecards/{{nextItem}}"><div class="rbut">&raquo;</div></a>
```

Two sample json entires:

```
{
"name": "Pecan Pie",
"shortname": "pecan-pie",
"drink":"0",
"dessert":"1",
"contributor": "Mark",
"totalt": "1h 5m",
"ingredients": "1 cup light brown sugar",
"steps": "Preheat oven to 400 degrees.",
},
{
"name": "Godfather",
"shortname": "godfather",
"drink":"1",
"dessert":"0",
"contributor": "Jack",
"totalt": "5m",
"ingredients": "amaretto",
"steps": "mix and drink",
},
```

Is there any way to have the buttons page through only the items that have a specific value?  In other words, the json file has several entries in it, but I only want the forward and back buttons to page through the entries with the value,     "drink":"1" and exclude entries with the value, "drink":"0".

Please note the json data has been shortened for clarity.  The real app has 8 dish categories, not just drinks and desserts.

**Update:** @MonVillalon
When I change the code in the controller from this:

```
$scope.dish = data;
```

to this:

```
$scope.dish = data.filter( function( item ){
return item.drink == 1 ;
});
```

It damages another controller (shown below) and HTML partial (this can be seen at [Problem Page](http://clarkecookbook.com/#/sides) Click on Mexican Rice).  Any ideas?

```
dishControllers.controller('DrinksController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get('js/all.json').success(function(data) {
$scope.dish = data;
$scope.dishOrder = 'name';

$scope.showDelete = function(itemDrink){
var testDrink = "1";

if(testDrink.indexOf(itemDrink) > -1){
   return true;
}
return false;
}

$scope.IsVisible = false;
        $scope.ShowHide = function () {
            $scope.IsVisible = !$scope.IsVisible;
        }
});
}]);
```

Comment: Just a minor thing: line 5 of the controller code you posted would be clearer as `$scope.IsVisible = !$scope.IsVisible`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll make the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to filter your results to only those things you want for example with [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Change the code

**from this:**

```
$scope.dish = data;
```

**to this:**

```
$scope.dish = data.filter( function( item ){
   return item.drink == 1 ;
});
```

Comment: See update above, your fix broke how another controller & HTML partial work.

Comment: Im sorry that page works for me, maybe you can elaborate on how it "broke".  The code for one controller shoudn't affect another unless they are  nested controllers and this doesn't seem to be the case in your app.

Comment: Yea, separate controllers shouldn't interact, that's what is strange.  I'm wondering if the problem lies in the HTML now.  The problem is complicated to explain, but I'll try.  Currently, my json file primarily has side dish entries, but a few others mixed in as well.  So the [link](http://clarkecookbook.com/#/sides) behaves correctly until the <ul> gets to 'Mexican Rice'.  This is because here in the json file your fix comes to the first item that is not a side and filtered out a dessert that sits right before 'Mexican Rice'.

Comment: As a result the page calls the next item in the json file and when you click 'Mexican Rice' it sends you to 'Potatoes Romanoff.'  This doesn't make sense to me.  The problem occurs all major browsers and within in-private browsing, so it should be occurring for anyone who visits the page.  I am incredibly appreciative of your assistance with this.

Comment: Ok, I had already tried this, but I tried again.  I used the filter you gave me on the second (problematic) controller and it works now so ignore my previous two comments.  I must have left left something out when I tried it earlier.  However, there was something interacting between the two controllers that shouldn't be occurring.  The only thing I changed was adding the filter to the second (problematic) controller.